# navbar links not working when the follwing script is added

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, navbar

Hello i wanted to close the navbar, when a user clicks outside the navbar, but due to some reason, below links are not working, in small screen sizes.
this is my html

```
<div>
  <jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/views/arthfc.jsp"></jsp:include>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light ">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Builder</a>
    <button id="navbarToggle" class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarText">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item ">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="builder_details.html">Builder Details</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="address_details.html">Address Details</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="management_details.html">Management Details</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="builder_profile.html">Builder Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="business_activity.html">Business Activity</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/logout">Logout</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

and the script is

```
$(function  () {

  $("#navbarToggle").blur(function  (event) {
    var screenWidth=window.innerWidth;
    if(screenWidth < 768){
      $("#navbarText").collapse('hide');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: the blur event will trigger before the click event on the menu item, so your menu is closed before you have the chance to click on the menu item

Comment: for instance i am in management page, i can go back to builder_details.html page, but cant go to builder_profile or business activity page, this is strange. but when i remove the script everything is working just as fine